# How to change <File> name in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanted to change file name when it was onChanged in .
So I did it like this.

```
import React from 'react';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';

function StoreInAws(){

    const send = (event) => {
        const file = event.target.files[0];
        const extenstion = file.name.substring(file.name.indexOf('.'));

        const date = new Date();
        const year = date.getFullYear().toString();
        const month = (date.getMonth()+1).toString();
        const day = date.getDate().toString();
        const hour = date.getHours().toString();
        const minute = date.getMinutes().toString();
        const second = date.getSeconds().toString();

        const changedFileName = year+month+day+hour+minute+second+extenstion;
        file.name = changedFileName
        console.log(file);
    }

    return(
        <Form.Control style={{width : '30%'}} type="file" onChange={send}/>
    );
}
export default StoreInAws;
```

But I got this error.

```
TypeError: Cannot set property name of #<File> which has only a getter
```

How can I change  name ??

Comment: You can't. As the error says, the name is read-only. For perhaps obvious security reasons, the `File` object is **very** locked down.

Comment: If you are trying to store it somewhere on the cloud, maybe you can send the new file name along with the file data and then store it there with a new file name.

Comment: there is a way to change filename in client side but it can be memory hog, so as _PratikWadekar_ suggested, trying change filename in server. Also please avoid monkey patching for formatting dates, use [`intl.DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat#examples) or some library.